# Convert Wikipedia Page Section to NSString Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, wikipedia

I'm working on some code that retrieves a section of a Wikipedia page as an NSString. I've found a constructed link online that returns the raw data of a section. For instance, to get the first section of the Wikipedia page on 'Boston', you would go to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Boston&action=raw&section=0.

And what I'm trying to achieve, is to convert that raw data into what can be seen on the normal Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston.

Now, at first, I thought I'd use regular expressions to parse out blocks that start with `{{` and end with `}}`. However, this proved to be problematic, and it deleted necessary text.

Then, I thought I could somehow find a wiki markup to html converter (present everywhere online) for Objective-C, but I had no luck there.

There are several similar questions on SO, but none of them seem to be clearly resolved: [Getting Wikipedia Article Summary using NSScanner Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772414/getting-wikipedia-article-summary-using-nsscanner-problem).

So, to resume, does anyone know how to parse a wiki page into an NSString?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PEG WikiText parser such as kiwi: https://github.com/AboutUs/kiwi

You can find kiwi's parsing output rules here: https://github.com/AboutUs/kiwi/blob/master/src/syntax.leg

You will need to download peg/leg to compile the leg file: http://piumarta.com/software/peg/

Comment: That does seem useful, but do you know if there's an Objective-C wrapper for it? I was originally leaning more towards a couple of regex expressions, but if this proves to be easy to implement, I might go for this instead.

Comment: None that I knew of. But if you don't want to write (and release) one you could always just build it as a command line tool and run it via NSTask from your app. Piece of cake. Wiki markup into STDIN, HTML from STDOUT. Done.

Comment: Updated answer with link to ".leg" file compiler. IIRC you'll need to install peg/leg via `./configure && sudo make && make install` (possibly without the `./configure && `) before attempting to compile kiwi. Oh and yes, I successfully compiled kiwi. Just a week ago. ;)

Comment: Alright thanks, got it to build :) Oh and final question: how do I pass the raw wiki markup to the 'parser' found in 'bin'?

Comment: [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend. Also check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OperatingSystem/Tasks/pipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000805-BAJEEBAB) and [this](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=nstask).